# Text above - Is my code good enough?

Tags: css, image, html, text

Is my code good enough to display text above image? It looks similar to the stackoverflow orange button "Ask Question", but not a button, not a link. It's just a text and the orange color around it. It works fine but I'm courious if the code looks fine and not stupid.

```
//css
    .date
    {
        float : left;
        width : 100px;
    }
//html   
<div class="date">
    <img src="orange.png">
    <div style="margin-top:-18px; margin-left:6px; color:#fff;">22.11.2012
    </div>
</div>
```

As result, the text is exactly above (in the center) of the image.

Comment: What does orange.png look like - why are you using an image instead of a `background-color`. Also this is not really appropriate for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Well, other than the missing `alt`, `width` and `height` attributes on your `img` tag, and the fact that you can combine your `margin` attributes in your 2nd div (`margin: -18px 0 0 6px`), it looks syntactically correct... unless I'm overlooking something.

Comment: `background-image` seems much more appropriate to me

Comment: Why are you doing inline css when you have it defined for elements at the top already?

Comment: Image tag is not syntactically correct xml.  Regardless, this might be better on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Background-image is not as beautiful (I should fix roundcorners for all browsers, use gradients etc). That's why I use an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as your concern was the aesthetics of the code, I recommend doing this:

```
// css
.date
{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
.date div
{
    margin-top: -18px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    color: #fff;
}

// html
<div class="date">
    <img src="orange.png">
    <div>22.11.2012</div>
</div>
```

The negative top margin may not be necessary if you can get `line-height:` worked in there, but I think this would probably look more professional. Inline CSS is never a good thing.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Something like that would be much better:

CSS:

```
.date {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: orange;
    color: #fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="date">
    22.11.2012
</span>
```

Anyway, you should read a bit about CSS basics. I made a quick search and [this](http://www.cssbasics.com/) could be, for example, a good start.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the code looks quite overcrowded. You could easily have made an anchor, styled like a button like so:

```
a{

padding: 7px;
background-color: orange;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
font-family: helvetica;
}

a:hover{

background: grey;

}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/s64LC/)
​